# Sitecore 8 (revision 150121), Analytics (MongoDB), Error "There is no row at position 0."

Tags: c#, mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-analytics

[image]Hello. my problem in Sitecore 8 Analytics - it's  ERROR 'There is no row at position 0.', when I view tabs 'PROFILE' and 'OVERVIEW' of not anonimous user in a 'EXPERIANCE PROFILE'.

This error exist also in updates of Sitecore 8. What is causing this error?.

Comment: Please can you clarify your question? It seems like you might be referring to the experience profile and not the User profile, but it's unclear. Also, can you post the whole error stack trace or a screenshot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### So, This problem is called by error of **Sitecore** developers.

Having analysed the code of "FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo" class and its methods I could find empty array (property "**Rows**" in a "**dataTable**" object), taken from elements. This causing out of range exception.

---

This problem can be fixed by implementing of your own class (copy of FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo) with adding **"if"-statement** for checking "Rows" field:

```
private bool ApplyPatternToOneProfile(ReportProcessorArgs args, DataRow profileRow)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        if (DataRowExtensions.Field<Guid>(profileRow, Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Schema.ProfileId.Name) == Guid.Empty)
            flag = false;
        ViewParameters retrievingBestPattern = CustomProcessorViewPatternProfile.GetParametersForRetrievingBestPattern(args, profileRow);
        DataTable dataTable = CustomerIntelligenceManager.ViewProvider.GenerateContactView(retrievingBestPattern).Data.Dataset[retrievingBestPattern.ViewName];
        if (dataTable.Rows != null && dataTable.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            if (!this.TryFillData<Guid>(profileRow, Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Schema.BestMatchedPatternId, dataTable.Rows[0], Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfilePatternMatch.Schema.PatternId.Name) || !this.TryFillData<string>(profileRow, Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Schema.BestMatchedPatternDisplayName, dataTable.Rows[0], Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfilePatternMatch.Schema.PatternDisplayName.Name) || !this.TryFillData<double>(profileRow, Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Schema.BestMatchedPatternGravityShare, dataTable.Rows[0], Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfilePatternMatch.Schema.PatternGravityShare.Name))
                flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
        }

        return flag;
    }
```

### UPDATE:

Alternatively you can solve this problem by the adding at least one pattern card in **Sitecore Marketing Control Panel** for corresponsing profile.(https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SC201503/Understanding+Profiles+and+Pattern+Cards;jsessionid=D03AC5B4F9F4B4E588538BC977BE2F6D)